# Laravel 5 Pivot table only saving first record

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a table that simply has the ids of other two tables, I want an n:m relationship but right now everytime I save a record it deletes the previous one if one of the two ids was already used.

My migration:

```
    Schema::create('show_user', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('show_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('show_id')->references('id')->on('shows');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

My Models:

USER

```
public function shows()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Show');
}
```

SHOWS

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

And this is how I save to the pivot table:

```
User::find($userid)->shows()->sync([$showid, $userid])
```

when I do this for user 1 (me), on show 5, it saves 1 and 5, when I try again for the same user on show 12, it saves 1 and 12 and deletes the 1 and 5 record from before. If I insert manually via phpMyAdmin I can add multiple records, but not using sync. I have tried also this, to the same result:

```
User::find($userid)->shows()->sync([$showid])
```

Comment: Try `attach()` instead of `sync()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `sync()` correctly. `sync()` is used to add **and remove** `Shows` from a `User`, and expects an array of `Show` `ids`. So if you call `sync([1,5])` you are adding the `Shows` with `ids` of 1 and 5 to the `User` and removing all other `Shows` previously associated with that `User`.

You can read about [inserting related-models in Laravel here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models), but you probably only need to know these three examples:

If `User` has relationships with `Shows` 3, 4, and 8, and you wanted to make sure that `User` only had relationships with `Shows` 4 and 5 you would do this:

```
User::find($userid)->shows()->sync([4,5]); // Removes 3 and 8; Adds 5
```

If `User` already has a relationship with `Show` 4 and you want to add `Show` 5 you would do this:

```
User::find($userid)->shows()->attach(5); // Adds 5
```

If `User` has relationships with `Shows` 3, 4, 5 and 8 and you want to remove 3 and 8 you would do this:

```
User::find($userid)->shows()->detach([3,8]); // Removes 3 and 8
```

After each of these examples, `User` would only have relationships with `Shows` 4 and 5.

Comment: The problem now is I get repeated combinations (like 4,5 2 times), is it because I need to add a unique constrain of the combination of the two to the table?

Comment: If you're using `sync` it shouldn't create duplicates. When you say `(4,5)` is in there twice do you mean there are two rows where `user_id=4` and `show_id=5` or are `Shows` 4 and 5 related to two different `Users`?

Comment: Also, `attach` doesn't check for duplicates. If you need to ensure there aren't any duplicates, you should use `sync`.

Comment: No, I mean user 4 can be related to more than one show (5, 6, 7...) but only once to each one.

Comment: Yeah, so you could create a unique constraint on the table to enforce that in the database, but if you're using `sync` then you shouldn't need to do that. I guess it's up to you.

Comment: In case someone else comes with my same issue, I added a migration with $table->unique( array('show_id','user_id') ); and that solved it using attach.

Answer (score 1):

if not work **sync** or two record save with sync.

**this code works**

```
$product->attributes()->sync([
        1 => ['product_id' => $product], 
        1 => ['provider_id' => $provider]
    ]);
```